# cPanel - does installing modules via easyapache overwrite php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, bash, ffmpeg, cpanel

I have a little script in bash which automates the installation of ffmpeg and ffmpeg's php module on a server. At the end of this, it appends `extension=ffmpeg.so` to the end of `php.ini` and restarts the `httpd` service.

My question is, in cPanel servers, say the user installs some other module using easy apache, would that overwrite the `php.ini` file. In which case, how do I make sure that the `extension=ffmpeg.so` is always added at the end?

One possible solution I thought of was to have a cron set which periodically checks the php.ini file but that doesn't look like the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the cronjob is a way solving this problem, even it's not a good one. But maybe there's a better solution: Try finding out what php file is exactly installing the package and add a exec("path to your script"); to it or try to work with includes in the php.ini